# Convert List<int>to List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

Can i convert `List<int>`to  `List<List<int>>` in c#?
When I use such construction

```
List<int>element=new List<int>();
List<List<int>>superElement= new List<List<int>>(element);
```

I get a fault,but can I do this in another way?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have data which have ID and vectors of integers .And I must save this vector in new super list?Can you understand me?

Comment: @MykhailoVashchuk: You should create a class that holds all you required information, and then have a single list which is a collection of these items. I would post an example, but I feel it wont be answering the question as it stands

Comment: @musefan Why should we feel ashamed? Someone asked a question, we answered. If everybody refused to answer, just because he/she feels the answer *should* be easy or obvious, why would users like Jon Skeet even waste their time to grace us with their knowledge?

Comment: @musefan - disagree entirely. The OP was clearly struggling to use a collection initializer but worded the question incorrectly, however it was clear to me and everyone else what he was trying to achieve. With regards to the easy rep wagon, I have gained 0 rep from answering this question and the highest vote is 3, therefore I don't possibly see how you can justify saying that.

Comment: @Nolonar: I am not saying don't answer because it's too easy. I am saying that it is firstly a duplicate (though there are too many duplicates to suggest one), and secondly, after identifying what the OP is trying to do, it is encouraging bad practice

Comment: @DarrenDavies: Yes, it was clear what he was trying to achieve, but what is more useful for the OP is to identify why, and them guide him down a more appropriate path

Comment: @musefan - that's why I posted my answer stating the collection initializer (The OP may not know this concept) as well as a link to MSDN.  I personally do not see how I could guide him any further.  If you can then you should post an answer yourself.

Comment: @musefan - you should feel ashamed for answering this and attempting to jump on the easy rep wagon :)

Comment: @DarrenDavies: I was half expecting it to cost me some rep actually ;)

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
List<List<int>> superElement = new List<List<int>>();
superElement.Add(element);
```

Comment: @MykhailoVashchuk Don't forget to accept whichever answer you feel is most useful to you ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
List<int>element=new List<int>();
List<List<int>>superElement= new List<List<int>> { element };
```

That'll work. You can't pass the list in the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
var element = new List<int>();
var superElement = new List< List<int> >(){ element };
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You can use the collection initializer

```
List<int> element = new List<int>();
List<List<int>> superElement = new List<List<int>> { element };
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to initialize the List, then

```
List<List<int>>superElement= new List<List<int>>();
```

works; if you want it to contain one (empty) element initially then

```
List<List<int>>superElement= new List<List<int>>{element};
```

will do it.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the fact I do not believe the other answers have really put in much effort to help, I am going to post what I believe to be a more complete and useful answer.

To start with, and for completeness I will show how to achieve what was actually trying to be done. To create a List of Lists you can do this:

```
List<int> element = new List<int>();
List<List<int>> superElement = new List<List<int>>();
superElement.Add(element);
```

But as it stands, it doesn't make a lot of sense why you would want to do this, and after some comment probing (hope it didn't hurt) we have discovered that you want to pair up an ID with a List of integers. I would suggest taking a different approach to this.

Personally, I would create a class to hold my data, and then create a single List for those items, like so:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public List<int> MyValues {get;set;}

    public MyData()
    {
        MyValues = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
List<int> element = new List<int>();
MyData data = new MyData();
data.ID = 1;
data.MyValues = element;

List<MyData> superElement = new List<MyData>();
superElement.Add(data);
```

Which would allow querying like so:

```
MyData data1 = superElement.SingleOrDeafult(x => x.ID == 1);
List<int> element = data1.MyValues;
```

Assuming you have Linq available.

---

An alternate method could be to use a dictionary, like so:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> superElement = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
superElement.Add(1, element);
```

where `1` is an ID, which you can call like so:

```
List<int> element = superElement[1];
```